# Get informed which button in popup window has been clicked

Tags: android, onclick, popup, imagebutton

Im trying to implement a feature of my small android app.
There is a image button, and a popup window will appear when I click it. According to which button in that popup window user click, that image button should change its image accordingly.
Like when i click 1 in the popup window, I should inform the button to update image to 1.

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

[image]

Comment: share some code you tried. Where is your popwindow and where is that Button??

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following method

```
public void setTabFor(Button btn) {

        for (Button button : btnArray) {
        if (button == btn) {

                if (button == button_one) {
                    Utils.setTabButton(R.drawable.left_selected, button_one);

                } else if (button == button_two) {

                    Utils.setTabButton(R.drawable.middle_selected, button_two);

                } else if (button == button_three) {
                    Utils.setTabButton(R.drawable.middle_selected, button_three);

                } else {
                    Utils.setTabButton(R.drawable.right_selected, button_four);

                }
}
```

Where setTabButton in Utils class is used to set backgrounddrawable:

```
public static void setTabButton(int drawable, Button... btn) {
        for (Button button : btn) {
            button.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cant find setTabButton in android doc. does this function exist?

Comment: please check my post..I have setTabButton as a static method in mu Utils class.You can follow likewise.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign an [ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aid) to each of the buttons in popup window. Then you have to implement a [listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) that will notify (and pass the ID to) your object (responsible for the image button) that a button was clicked and your object will update the image button according to the received ID.

Comment: So, I should implement onClick function. However, how do I pass this ID to that button? Which technique i apply to communicate between this button and popup window?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
First of all,you have to assign unique Id for all image button that you used in your application.then which button you clicked with help of Ids u can display buttons as per your choice.

I hope it will help you and solve your problem very soon.